# iOS - sqlite database replacement made replaced db readonly

Tags: ios, testing, sqlite, automation

While working in an iOS app, i have created a database when app launches. I also had a preloaded database in app/resource which actually same database with some preloaded data. When i replaced app database with preloaded app/resource database with NSFileManager copy API,

```
[fileManager copyItemAtURL:testDbUrl toURL:destination error:&error];
```

#### Problem

I found newly replaced database became readonly. I cannot execute any insert operation but reading is fine. How can i make newly replaced database writable.

Comment: Are there any open connections?

Comment: how can i find it?

Comment: You should know where your app opens any databases ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When i reinitialize my cache  db object, it became writable, so i assume there were some connection related issue. @CL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved the issue by re-initializing my database helpers/managers.

### Solution

1. Make sure that the database is replaced without any exception/error from file managers
2. Make sure that the newly replaced database managers is re-initialized and reopened